# Can't run PHP file in SVN repository

Tags: php, ubuntu, svn

I have an svn repository setup in Ubuntu Server 14.04 setup with LAMP. I can access the repository using my browser via http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/svn/testrepo/ and I can view HTML files with it. However, when I click .php files, it just shows me the source code.

I can run both .html and .php files in /var/www/html but not in the svn folders.

Do I have to configure something? Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. I'm running apache, outside the repo directory, PHP files execute, inside the php file gets downloaded or the source is shown.

Answer (score -1):

You are just browsing your SVN repository, which will only show you the contents of the files in there as raw source code.

To actually execute the PHP files you need a web sever that is able to parse and execute PHP. Examples of web servers that can be used for this are Apache and Nginx.